# How to serve marketing content and web application from the same domain?

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system, hosting, web-hosting

I would like to serve up marketing content as well as my web application from the same domain www.mydomain.com

Often, I see websites use a content management system to serve up marketing content from **www.theirdomain.com** but accessing the web app happens from **app.theirdomain.com**. This is fairly straightforward.

I want my marketing content to be at:

- www.mydomain.com
- www.mydomain.com/pricing, etc.

And my web app content to be at:

- www.mydomain.com/login
- www.mydomain.com/dashboard, etc.

What are the common approaches to putting both types of systems on the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most limiting factors I have at the moment with hosting my CMSes on Heroku, each app needs to be served off a separate subdomain.

If you're running your own servers you can still break each app (e.g., marketing vs dashboard) into a separate codebase. And then use a reverse proxy such as nginx (http://nginx.org/en/) or HAProxy (http://www.haproxy.org/) to send requests to `/login` and `/dashboard` to your dashboard app, and for everything else to go through to your marketing app.